# PayPal/Stripe - Allow one user to pay another through Website

Tags: django, paypal, stripe-payments, e-commerce

Goal: Allow a user on my website to pay another user(merchant) for a service via either PayPal or Stripe. I would like to take a percentage of the purchase amount and the remaining percentage would go to the merchants account.

I've successfully added both Stripe and PayPal to my Django app, and successfully integrated a payment portal, but the default use-case appears to be for the user to send a payment to owner of the website (owner of the paypal/stripe account) via a client ID. For paypal, I figured out how to specify the payee as the merchant, rather than myself, but there is still not a clear way to split the payment. I would not like to accept 100% of the payment and then pay the merchant. The only payment I should receive is the percent of the payment at the time of the transaction..

Is it possible to implement this type of payment schema through Stripe Merchant onboarding? The only route to achieve this through paypal as far as I can tell is PayPal partnership (paypal marketplace), which is for larger businesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Split funds from a single charge between different sellers using Connect

### Connect

> Stripe does not support the splitting of funds from a single charge
>   among multiple sellers for compliance reasons. As a platform using
>   Connect, you will need to ensure that there is still a one-to-one
>   relationship between a charge and one of your connected accounts.

## PayPal User Agreement

> 4.5 No Surcharges. You agree that you will not impose a surcharge or any other fee for accepting PayPal as a payment method. You may charge
>   a handling fee in connection with the sale of goods or services, as
>   long as the handling fee does not operate as a surcharge and is not
>   higher than the handling fee you charge for non-PayPal transactions.

You will have to be the middleman and take payment, split it and then send the rest to the paypal user or make two charges, 1. The cost 2. Your fee.

Comment: Looking in the stripe docs. I'm wondering how that above squares with this: 
"Enable other businesses to accept payments directly
Facilitate direct payments between other businesses and their own customers.

Overview
This guide walks you through how to enable your users to accept payments, move a portion of their earnings into your balance, and pay out the remainder to your users’ bank accounts. We’ll illustrate these concepts with an example of a store builder platform that enables businesses to set up their own Internet stores."

Comment: The surcharge clause doesn't apply to marketplace fees. The surcharge clause is about charging higher prices to pay for goods with PayPal vs. alternative payment methods such as cash, for example. Basically not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

> The only route to achieve this through PayPal as far as I can tell is PayPal partnership (paypal marketplace), which is for larger businesses.

That's correct. Without that type of partnership, you would need to accept the *whole* payment and use [something like Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts), which of obviously does not meet your requirement of only accepting some percent.

(There was a very old way to do it -- Adaptive Payments Chained Payments, but you can forget it ever existed; no longer ever available)

I suppose, technically, the deprecated [EC Parallel Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ht-ec-parallelPayments/) is still open and "usable", but that's an observable split and designed for use cases like paying for a Hotel and Airfaire at once. Really not good for marketplace use, and it's also quite old and may go away soon due to that deprecation. I would *not* recommend using it for anything, much less marketplaces -- just covering the bases.